# KivyMD: How to get text from TextField added from within python

Tags: python, kivymd

So I have code looking like this:

```
self.ids.container.add_widget(
    MDTextField(id="a")
)
```

When I later try to access the inputted text by:

```
text = self.ids["a"].text
```

I Get a `KeyError: 'a'`

How come? And how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I figured it out:

### Solution

```
def __init__(self):
    self.tf = []

def get_field(self):
    for i in range(3):
        tf = MDTextField(id=str(i), hint_text="Alt"+str(i))
        self.tf.append(tf)
        self.ids.container.add_widget(tf)

def print_it(self):
    for itm in self.tf:
        print(itm.text)
```

As you can see, the solution is to store the MDTextField widget in a list within the class.